# Google таблицы. Как можно реализовать автообновление для столбца, в котором значения выбираются по "Проверке данных" из списка"?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

То есть чтоб при изменении диапазона из которого берутся значения для списка по "Проверке данных" данные в списке, которые уже введены, обновлялись автоматически?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повесьте в AppScript функцию OnEdit() на диапазон списка, при срабатывании пусть скрипт вносит изменения